# how to read hex file from arduino using USB port?

Tags: arduino, hex

i have a programed arduino board (mega2560) and i want to read hex file from this, but i cant reach to ICSP port. Is there any way to read hex or binary file from an arduino board using USB or Rx/Tx port??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read more about avrdude:
using this command you can download the hex into your machine it should be some thing as follow
avrdude -p m1280 -c stk500 -e -U flash:w:xxxxx.hex

Answer (score 0):

Hi I should use comments but I don't have that privilege... I guess maybe you need to rephrase or break down your question. First, what is the source? Are you reading a file from your desktop/laptop? Second, I'm not sure what do you mean by hex file, Third, which port is the input for Arduino? ICSP or USB Tx/Rx?

Comment: Hi, thanks , i have a programed Mega2560, this board programed by my friend but i haven't the source code and i want to read(download) hex code from the board.